# How to see '\n' characters when outputting f.read(20)?

Tags: python, file, newline

If I print f.readlines(), I am able to see the '\n' characters included, 
`['\n', 'Avoid touching eyes, nose and mouth\n', '\n', 'Why? .....]`

something like f.read(20) produces:

`Avoid touching eyes`

which converts the '\n' into actual empty line.

How to see actual '\n' included within f.read(20)

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think printing `f.readline()` will show the `\n` literally.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: If you're seeing `\n`, the file must contain a literal slash followed by `n`, not a newline. And you'll see those with both `readline()` and `read()`.

Comment: Unless you share some actual code that shows what you're doing, you're only going to get guesses at possible answers. There's no such thing as a dumb question, but there's definitely bad ones - and they get you bad answers.

Comment: @Barmar Sorry I added an example.

Comment: You changed from `f.readline()` to `f.readlines()`. That makes a big difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `repr()` function to get the literal representation of a string, rather than interpreting the control characters.

```
print(repr(f.read(20)))
```

`repr()` shows what you would have to type as a string literal in a program, so it also puts quotes around the output.

When you print a list, it prints the literal representations of all the list elements. But when you print a string, it interprets the control characters.